# Riverpod GoRouter Authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, riverpod, gorouter

I'm using riverpod to manage my app states and go_router.
I'm using Firebase auth provider and have a Firestore document (FirestoreUser) for each user that matches on auth uid.
For the app to function properly I need to do the following:  When a user is authenticated, I need retrieve a Firestore document (FirestoreUser) as a stream (document matched on auth uid).

**my providers are**

```
final signinProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<SigninController,SigninState>(
        (ref)=>SigninController(ref.watch(authRepoProvider))
);

final authRepoProvider = Provider<AuthenticationRepository>(
        (_) => AuthenticationRepository()
);
```

the problem is while logging in If user profile is not finished I want them to finish account conditionally: i.e.

```
documentSnapshot =await usersRef.doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).get();
      if(!documentSnapshot!.exists){
        context.go(FinishUpProfile.routeName);
      }

signinWithEmailAndPassword(BuildContext context)async{
    if(!state.status.isValidated)return;
    state = state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionInProgress);
    try{
      await _authenticationRepository.signinWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: state.email.value,
          password: state.email.value
      );
      documentSnapshot =await usersRef.doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).get();
      if(!documentSnapshot!.exists){
        context.go(FinishUpProfile.routeName);
      }
      currentUser = user_model.User.fromDocument(documentSnapshot!);
      state = state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionSuccess);
    } on SigninWithEmailAndPasswordFailure catch(error){
      state = state.copyWith(
          status: FormzStatus.submissionFailure,
          errorMessage: error.code
      );
      showInSnackBar('Invalid Credential : Unable to login',context);
    }
  }

  void signinGoogle(context)async {
    try {
      await _authenticationRepository.signInWithGoogle();
      state = state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionSuccess);
      documentSnapshot =await usersRef.doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).get();
      if(!documentSnapshot!.exists) {
        context.go(FinishUpProfile.routeName);
      }
      currentUser = user_model.User.fromDocument(documentSnapshot!);
      // if(!currentUser!.isVerified!)await Navigator.pushNamed(
      //     context, VerifyAccount.routeName);
      if(currentUser!=null)Navigator.of(context,rootNavigator: true).pop();

    } on SigninWithEmailAndPasswordFailure catch (error) {
      state = state.copyWith(
          status: FormzStatus.submissionFailure,
          errorMessage: error.code
      );
      showInSnackBar('Invalid Credential : Unable to login',context);
    }
  }
```

**but when I remove //documentSnapshot =await usersRef.doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).get();
it works**

```
signinWithEmailAndPassword(BuildContext context)async{
    if(!state.status.isValidated)return;
    state = state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionInProgress);
    try{
      await _authenticationRepository.signinWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: state.email.value,
          password: state.email.value
      );

      context.go(FinishUpProfile.routeName);
      currentUser = user_model.User.fromDocument(documentSnapshot!);
      state = state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionSuccess);
    } on SigninWithEmailAndPasswordFailure catch(error){
      state = state.copyWith(
          status: FormzStatus.submissionFailure,
          errorMessage: error.code
      );
      showInSnackBar('Invalid Credential : Unable to login',context);
    }
  }
```

the SignIn widget is :

```
class SignIn extends ConsumerWidget {


const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,WidgetRef widgetRef) {
    final signinState = widgetRef.watch(signinProvider);
    final showEmailError = signinState.email.invalid?Email.showEmailErrorMessege(signinState.email.error):null;
    final showPasswordError = signinState.password.invalid?Password.showPasswordErrorMessage(signinState.password.error):null;
    final signinController = widgetRef.read(signinProvider.notifier);
    final bool _isValidated = signinState.status.isValidated;
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextInputField(
          hintText: "Email",
          errorText: showEmailError,
          onChanged: (email){
            widgetRef.read(signinProvider.notifier).onEmailChange(email);
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 16,
        ),
        TextInputField(
          isObsecured: true,
          hintText: "Password",
          errorText: showPasswordError,
          onChanged: (password){
            widgetRef.read(signinProvider.notifier).onPasswordChange(password);
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 6,
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, ForgotPassword.routeName);
          },
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text(
                'Forgot Password',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFF6574FF)
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Container(
          child: FFButtonWidget(
            onPressed:()async{

              if(!_isValidated){
                return;
              }
              await signinController.signinWithEmailAndPassword(context);

            },
            text: 'Log in',
            showLoadingIndicator: true,
            options: FFButtonOptions(
              width: ResponsiveWidget.isSmallScreen(context)
                  ?screenSize.width/1.5
                  :screenSize.width/3,
              height: 50,
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              textStyle: FenoteAbewTheme.bodyText1,
              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: 1,
              ),
              borderRadius:50,
            ),
          ).animated([
            animationsMap[
            'buttonOnPageLoadAnimation1']!
          ]),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 8,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
          child: Row(
            children:const [
              Expanded(child: Divider()),
              Text('OR'),
              Expanded(child: Divider())
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 8,
        ),
        Container(
          child: FFButtonWidget(
            onPressed:()async{
              final signinController = widgetRef.read(signinProvider.notifier);
              signinController.signinGoogle(context);
            },
            icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.google),
            text: 'Login with Google',
            showLoadingIndicator: true,
            options: FFButtonOptions(
              width: ResponsiveWidget.isSmallScreen(context)
                  ?screenSize.width/1.5
                  :screenSize.width/3,
              height: 50,
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              textStyle: FenoteAbewTheme.bodyText1,
              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: 1,
              ),
              borderRadius:50,
            ),
          ).animated([
            animationsMap[
            'buttonOnPageLoadAnimation1']!
          ]),
        ),

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

***if I dont remove the await //documentSnapshot =await usersRef.doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).get();
I encounter the Error***

```
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4241:9                                                                         <fn>
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4254:14
[_debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup]
```